# MobileFirst and Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, ibm-mobilefirst

I would like to understand whether I can activate Proguard obfuscation within an **hybrid** app (Android) developed with IBM MobileFirst 7.1 or Proguards is only available for native apps within the IBM MobileFirst library ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use ProGuard with Hybrid applications for the Android environment.

Read more here:

- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/videos/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-foundation-android-proguard/
- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/c_pg_obfus_intro.html?lang=en

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, for Hybrid application I mean 90% HTML code. Is Proguard able to obfuscate only the 10% of native code in the app ?

Comment: Hybrid is still native. You just run HTML inside of it. ProGuard will relate only to the native part

Answer (score 0):

```
You can obfuscation your web resource by google compiler see the below link.
[https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/obfuscating_javascript_code?lang=en][1]

In the comment section of this link, you will find ANT script for that.
```

Steps to follow:
1) download "Google closure compiler" and put it in your project root directory.
2) Make a ANT file ObfuscateJS.xml. In classpath put the path of jar if it is folder that put folder name in the place of path_of_jar. In property tag put your project name. You can add multiple files here in jscomp tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
    <chmod perm="666">
        <fileset dir="${androidWebResourcesFolder}">
            <include name="**/*.js"></include>
        </fileset>
    </chmod>

    <jscomp compilationLevel="simple" output="${androidWebResourcesFolder}/js/xyz.js">
        <sources dir="${androidWebResourcesFolder}/js">
            <file name="workflow.js">
            </file>
        </sources>
    </jscomp> 
    <jscomp compilationLevel="simple" output="${androidWebResourcesFolder}/js/index.js">
        <sources dir="${androidWebResourcesFolder}/js">
            <file name="index.js">
            </file>
        </sources>
    </jscomp> 
</target>
```

3) right click on ObfuscateJS.xml and click on ANT build.

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.

Comment: check updated post if you will find any problem reply on this post i will help to solve the problem. @AnirudhSharma